# How to track the fullscreen event or vice versa google map angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I'm trying to run the showInfoWindow function only when the map is open at full screen, but so far I can't trace this event.

How can I track the fullsreen event to trigger the function only when the map is open to full screen? How do I move the map-place-selected-wrapper block inside the agm-info-window in this case?

```js
  places: Places[] = [];
 
  mapPlaceSelected: any = null;
  mapPlaceSelectedShow = false;
  loadMoreIndex = 12;

  mapCenter: any = [0, 0];
  infoWindowOpened: any = null;




showInfoWindow(infoWindow: any, i: number) {
    if (this.infoWindowOpened === infoWindow) {
      return;
    }

    if (this.infoWindowOpened !== null) {
      this.infoWindowOpened.close();
    }

    this.infoWindowOpened = infoWindow;
    console.log(infoWindow);
  }

  mapPlaceClick(place: Places, i: number) {
    this.mapPlaceSelected = null;
    this.mapPlaceSelectedShow = true;

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.mapPlaceSelected = place;
    }, 1);

  }
```

```html
<div class="places-map-wrapper" (clickOutside)="mapPlaceHide()">
        <agm-map
          [latitude]="mapCenter[0]"
          [longitude]="mapCenter[1]"
          *ngIf="places.length"
          [zoom]="8"
          [disableDefaultUI]="false"
          [styles]="styles">

          <ng-container *ngFor="let place of places; let i = index">
            <agm-marker
              *ngIf="place.lat && place.long"
              (markerClick)="mapPlaceClick(place, i); showInfoWindow(infoWindow, i);"
              [latitude]="place.lat"
              [longitude]="place.long"
              [iconUrl]="'assets/img/map.svg'">
              <agm-info-window #infoWindow>

              </agm-info-window>
            </agm-marker>
          </ng-container>

        </agm-map>
        <div class="map-place-selected-wrapper" [class.active]="mapPlaceSelectedShow">
          <span class="b_delete_image" (click)="mapPlaceHide()"></span>
          <ng-container *ngIf="mapPlaceSelected">
            <ng-container
              [ngTemplateOutlet]="placeItem"
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{place:mapPlaceSelected, index:1}">
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Resolved! I needed to add (fullscreenchange)="fullscreenchange()"

```js
fullscreen: boolean = false;


fullscreenchange() {
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
      this.fullscreen = true;
      console.log('fullscreen = true!');
    } else {
      this.fullscreen = false;
      console.log('fullscreen = false!');
    }
  }
```

```html
 <agm-map
      [latitude]="mapCenter[0]"
      [longitude]="mapCenter[1]"
      *ngIf="places.length"
      [zoom]="8"
      [disableDefaultUI]="false"
      (fullscreenchange)="fullscreenchange()"
      [styles]="styles">
</agm-map>
```

```js
 fullscreen: boolean = false;


fullscreenchange() {
    if (document.fullscreenElement) {
      this.fullscreen = true;
      console.log('fullscreen = true!');
    } else {
      this.fullscreen = false;
      console.log('fullscreen = false!');
    }
  }
```

```html
      <div class="places-map-wrapper" (clickOutside)="mapPlaceHide()">
        <agm-map
          [latitude]="mapCenter[0]"
          [longitude]="mapCenter[1]"
          *ngIf="places.length"
          [zoom]="8"
          [disableDefaultUI]="false"
          (fullscreenchange)="fullscreenchange()"
          [styles]="styles">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let place of places; let i = index">
            <agm-marker
              *ngIf="place.lat && place.long"
              (markerClick)="mapPlaceClick(place, i);"
              [latitude]="place.lat"
              [longitude]="place.long"
              [iconUrl]="'assets/img/map.svg'">
              <agm-info-window  #infoWindow *ngIf="fullscreen">
                <div class="map-place-selected-wrapper" [class.active]="mapPlaceSelectedShow">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="mapPlaceSelected">
                    <ng-container
                      [ngTemplateOutlet]="placeItem"
                      [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{place:mapPlaceSelected, index:1}">
                    </ng-container>
                  </ng-container>
                </div>
              </agm-info-window>
            </agm-marker>
          </ng-container>

        </agm-map>
        <div *ngIf="!fullscreen" class="map-place-selected-wrapper" [class.active]="mapPlaceSelectedShow">
          <span class="b_delete_image" (click)="mapPlaceHide()"></span>
          <ng-container *ngIf="mapPlaceSelected">
            <ng-container
              [ngTemplateOutlet]="placeItem"
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{place:mapPlaceSelected, index:1}">
            </ng-container>
          </ng-container>
        </div>

      </div>
```